# Managing useful duplicate files in Git

Tags: git, version-control

I am new to Git and would like to know how best to handle duplicate files.

Suppose I have the following Git directory structure:

```
myProject/
myProject/Server/
myProject/AndroidApp/
```

Both Server/ and AndroidApp/ have a few shared files, (e.g. MyUtilities.java). I think that the set of shared files is small enough to preclude making a separate package or directory for them. Now, I really don't want to create two copies of each file, but essentially Server/MyUtilities.java must be the same as AndroidApp/MyUtilities.java. What should I do?

Comment: What is your hesitation with creating two copies of each file? Is it co-managing the pair or size? Either way, git has solutions for both of those scenarios.

Comment: I don't want to have to take the separate step of insuring that both files are exactly the same. I guess that is what you mean by "co-management". And what is the git solution?

Comment: I don't see what git has to do with any of this.

Comment: Your two projects would be two repos and the shared lib would be in its own, third repo that gets consumed by both as a "submodule".

Comment: "I think that the set of shared files is small enough to preclude making a separate package or directory for them." If you're asking this question, I seriously doubt that's true. Programming languages have ways of reusing code for a reason.

Comment: The issue is not whether the common files are small enough to warrant its own repository, but whether the `AndroidApp` and `Server` each belong in their own repository. Do they strictly evolve together, or are they more loosely coupled?

Comment: @Novelocrat: They strictly evolve together. Some functionality may be performed on either the Android app or the server, depending on parameters. So they share some code that is exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

If they are the same file, you might be better off making a symbolic link from one:

Example in Linux/OSX
`ln -s myProject/Server/MyUtilities.java myProject/AndroidApp/MyUtilities.java`

Comment: btw this is not a git thing, but an OS thing. Git should be able to handle symbolic links just fine though

Comment: If I make a symbolic link and check it in, it will be checked in as a file, not as a link, right? Wouldn't it then be the case that when someone else updates their repository, they will pull in both separate files, and then you would have two distinct files (as opposed to a file and a symbolic link)?

Comment: That will depend on your `core.symlinks` configuration but normally it WILL store it as a link, not as a separate file

Answer (score 1):

You should do what you said yourself: make a separate directory for common files.

Or you could try running Git on top of a filesystem with built-in deduplication!

Comment: No need for a special file system; if the files are identical, Git stores only one copy. Of course there will be two copies in your working area.

Answer (score 1):

You should manage this based on the structure of your project, not on how Git will handle it.

The first question you should ask yourself is: if you make a change to `myProject/Server/MyUtilities.java`, do you always want to make the same change to `myProject/AndroidApp/MyUtilities.java`?

If so, then they're logically one file that's used in two different places, and you should put it in a common area and reference it from where you need to.

And you can change your mind later; if you find that `AndroidApp` needs a different version of it, you can always move things around.

As I said, don't worry about Git.  Internally, files in a Git repository are stored based on their contents; the file name is the sha1 checksum of the contents of the file.  (It's not quite that straightforward, but nearly so.)  If two files happen to be identical, Git will store a single copy and refer to it as needed.  If you change one copy, the references will be updated -- but the older version, which you can still access, still refers to the one copy.  Of course you'll have two copies in your working area, but Git itself only stores one.

Symbolic links are a tempting idea, and they can certainly be useful (and Git does handle symlinks), but I think that either storing two copies of the file or putting a single copy in a common directory is likely to be a better solution.

**EDIT :** To clarify what I'm suggesting, I think the best approach is to have just one copy of any logical files -- no duplicate files, no symlinks.

For example, you could create a new directory `Common` containing `MyUtilities.java`:

```
myProject/Common/MyUtilities.java
myProject/Server/ServerFoo.java
myProject/AndroidApp/AndroidBar.java
```

I'm not intimately familiar with Java, but I presume it gives you some way to refer to things in another file without having to have that file in the same directory.  In other words, you shouldn't need `myProject/Server/MyUtilities.java` at all, either as a copy or as a symlink; just refer to `myProject/Common/MyUtilities.java` from `myProject/Server/ServerFoo.java`.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: If I create a third directory for these common files, I would still need to reference them from the original two directories, which would necessitate the use of a symbolic link or something again, right?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010: Not necessarily; see my updated answer.  I don't *think* you need multiple copies, either as physical copies or as symlinks -- unless I've misunderstood your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

It does not consume any extra space if a file in the repository is duplicated. It is because git's storage is a content-addressable system (i.e. same hash for that duplicated file) .

If you do not want your working copy to consume extra space, then use symbolic link. Git can keep symbolic links in Unix like systems, but symbolic links in Windows is currently not supported well.

Comment: You do not only want to have it use no disk space, you also want to have the code change on both locations if you change one.